# (Angular) "Property 'display' is used before its initialization"

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a timer in Angular in which I should be able to save the various values of the time (start, finish and length, right now just length) and "print" them in HTML.

I tried inserting this.display in the length property of the interface "result" but it says "Property 'display' is used before its initialization". I think I should be using the ngOnInit or the constructor in some way but I'm unsure on how to proceed.

I've created the function clearTimer() which should both work as a function for clearing the current displayed timer and saving the value in a list.

Feel free to also correct my current code if you don't find it optimal for its purpose.

HTML:

```html
<div class="modalbox" [class.active]="modalboxActive">
  <div class="modal">
    <p>What did you do?</p>

    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="activity.name" #task />
    <button
      (click)="addTask(task.value)"
      (click)="task.value = ''"
      [disabled]="activity.name === ''"
      (click)="clearTimer()"
    >
      OK
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="boxSuper">
  <div class="boxLeft">
    <div class="containerUp">
      <button id="start" (click)="startTimer()">START</button>
      <button id="pause" (click)="pauseTimer()">PAUSE</button>
      <button id="stop" (click)="stopTimer()">STOP</button>
    </div>
    <div class="containerDown">
      <p>{{ display }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxRight">
    <div class="containerLeft">
      <div class="leftList">
        <ul class="listElement" *ngFor="let item of duration">
          <li>
            Length:
            <span>{{ item.length }}</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="containerRight">
      <div class="rightList">
        <ul class="listElement" *ngFor="let item of list">
          <li>
            Activity:
            <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```js
import { importExpr } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
import { Activity } from '../activity';
import { Result } from '../result';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-timer',
  templateUrl: './timer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./timer.component.css'],
})
export class TimerComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {}
  time: number = 0;
  display: string | undefined;
  interval: any;
  modalboxActive = false;

  activity: Activity = {
    name: '',
  };
  list: any[] = [];

  result: Result = {
    start: undefined,
    end: undefined,
    length: this.display, // here display gets marked in red and it says "Property 'display' is used before its initialization."
  };
  duration: any[] = [];

  addTask(item: string) {
    this.list.push({ name: this.activity.name });
    this.activity.name = '';
    this.modalboxActive = false;
  }

  clearTimer() {
    this.duration.push({ length: this.result.length });
  }

  startTimer() {
    console.log('go');
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.time === 0) {
        this.time++;
      } else {
        this.time++;
      }
      this.display = this.transform(this.time);
    }, 1000);
  }
  transform(value: number): string {
    var sec_num = value;
    var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - hours * 3600) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60;
    return hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
  }
  pauseTimer() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
  stopTimer() {
    this.modalboxActive = true;
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    console.log('show');
  }
}
```

"Result" interface:

```js
export interface Result {
  start: string | undefined;
  end: string | undefined;
  length: string | undefined;
}
```

Comment: This is because `display` is not defined. That means you need a `this.display = 'something'` to use it. Maybe you can try `length: this.display || undefined` ?

Comment: Yeah, in fact I think I should be using the ngOnInit or the constructor but I'm unsure on how to do it. I tried writing `length: this.display || undefined` inside of "result" but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Actually `display` is not assigned at the beginning, so what if you try simply `length: undefined` ?

Comment: It still won't work sadly.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work ? I reproduced on a Stackblitz and we don't get any error when we use directly `length: undefined` into your object `result: Result`.

Comment: If I remember correctly it didn't work, maybe I missed something, anyhow I managed to find a solution.